# Adding a Spot Color Channel to .Tiff Images with Python

Tags: python, image-processing, printing, python-imaging-library, photoshop

Im searching for a Solution to Automate some UV-Printer Tasks from Images that are allready processed trough Python and Uploaded to Dropbox. Everything exept the Part of adding a new Channel to the .tiff File. Basicly the Transperancy of the Image should be unchanged, just another Channel in full red should be added on top of the all colors that are in the Image.

On Photoshop you would Mask the existing Elements, create a new Channel and fill the empty mask from the Images Elements Refference with red, so that the Channel is right behind the Text and not visible.

I have found some Code, but im not quiet sure if this brings me to the Solution i need.
Maybe somone has more expertise on that topic and could help me out and maybe edit and improve the code for it, to have a final solution.
I would appriciate anything!

Things i have found are:

```
from PIL import Image

def add_spot_color_channel(input_file, output_file, spot_color, region_coordinates):
    # Open the existing TIFF image
    image = Image.open(input_file)

    # Convert the image to RGBA mode
    image = image.convert("RGBA")

    # Extract the alpha channel
    alpha_channel = image.getchannel("A")

    # Extract the RGB channels
    r, g, b = image.split()

    # Create a new channel with the spot color
    spot_color_channel = Image.new("L", image.size, 0)
    spot_color_channel.paste(spot_color[0], region_coordinates)  # Assuming spot_color is a tuple (R, G, B)

    # Combine the new spot color channel with the existing RGB channels and alpha channel
    new_image = Image.merge("RGBA", (r, g, b, alpha_channel, spot_color_channel))

    # Save the result to the output file
    output_file = output_file.replace('.tiff', '_with_spot_color.tiff')
    new_image.save(output_file)

# Example usage
input_file = "existing_image.tiff"
output_file = "image_with_spot_color.tiff"
spot_color = (255, 0, 0)  # Red spot color
region_coordinates = (100, 100, 200, 200)  # (left, top, right, bottom)

add_spot_color_channel(input_file, output_file, spot_color, region_coordinates)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URcRk.jpg)

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/nelrijhsdqfmkc6n4ez26/h?rlkey=qwyuzhob8a6llxl2awr50tjz5&dl=0

Comment: Could you include an input image and manually create the output image so people can visually see what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think what you want is not the creation of a new channel, exactly. I think what you are after is a modification of the red channel.

Comment: Printing with UV Ink and with .Tiff has few Stages,

Comment: you can include 2 new Channels into a .Tiff file, one channel will add a solution on to the workpiece so the Ink is held better on the Workpiece, the other channel you add is a Base layer of white Ink, why this Channel needs to be Red i don't know, but it is not changin the original Red Channel since the other R,G,B,A Channels are to print the desired Image on top of the Spot Color Channel, so the Added Spot color Channel needs to have Shape of all (R,G,B) channels so the White Base layer is evenly trough out the whole Print underneth.

Comment: I can't find any Information on this, either way its a strong-held secret about how its done, because i can't imagine that everybody is doing it manually with Photoshop if you have a bigger Production scale.

Comment: Is there any way you could provide the original .tiff file and the new .tiff file, saved after creating the spot channel? Given that the extra channels are important, you probably can't use Stack Overflow's image hosting, but could you host the files elsewhere and provide a link?

Comment: I have added a Link with 3 different files, one has no channel added, one channel, and two channels, there is no difference in the two channels, just the printer interprets those two channels to use another Ink/base coating, breaking down the .tif  file may show how the channel is stored, even when you open the File on a Window Image viewer some cant interpret the image right as the image without a spot color channel, if opened with Photoshop, the image gets split up into the Channels and you see the image properly.

Comment: But there is no issue on that, its just to find a way to have the Existing Channels of the Base image ''No spot color channel'' to merge as a new Channel in full red.

Comment: From a TIFF standard point of view these are just `PhotometricInterpretation=SEPARATE` (CMYK, not RGB) with `ExtraSamples=[UNSPECIFIED, ...]`. The details about the extra samples, identifying them as spot colors, are buried inside proprietary TIFF tags. Tag #34377 (ImageResources) seems most relevant. You can parse and rewrite it with the [psdtags](https://pypi.org/project/psdtags/) library, but it will take some reverse engineering to reproduce what PhotoShop does. For example, the `ALTERNATE_SPOT_COLORS` resource seems to contain the actual spot color...